# Array keeps clearing before a new element is added using spread operator and useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spread

Every time I click on an element call the `handleUpdateCanvasCards()` function the `textArray` clears and the new element is added. I'm trying to use the spread operator to build up an array of elements based on user clicking but it keep clearing. Not sure if it is the `useEffect()` that is breaking things?

```
function App() {
  const [textArray, setTextArray] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);

  function handleClick(option: Option) {
    setSelected(option);
  }
[...]
  function handleUpdateCanvasCards(info: string) {
    setTextArray([...textArray, info]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selected === "Phonics") {
      const phonicsData = spellingData.map((w: Spelling, i: number) => {
        return (
          <div
            onClick={() => handleUpdateCanvasCards(w.spelling)}
            key={i}
          >
            <h1>{w.spelling}</h1>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });
      setData(phonicsData);
    }

    if (selected === "Morphology") {
      const morphemes = morphemeData.map((m: Affix, i: number) => {
        return (
          <div
            onClick={() => handleUpdateCanvasCards(m.affix_name)}
            key={i}
          >
            <h1>{m.affix_name}</h1>

          </div>
        );
      });
      setData(morphemes);
    }
  }, [selected]);

[...]

export default App;
```

Comment: I think that it has to do with some stale state messing with function memoization. Just for curiosity, try removing the dependency array (all the array not just the "selected" state) from the useEffect() hook.

Comment: Thanks for the response, when I remove it the array does seem to work as expected however I get this error:

Warrning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Comment: Do the following:
handleUpdateCanvasCards = (info: string) =>(event)=> {
    setTextArray([...textArray, info]);
  }

and then onClick = {handleUpdateCanvasCards(m.affix_name)}